# Redirection of stdout and stderr to two different log files

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, paramiko

Is it possible to redirect stdout and stderr in two different text files? I am struggling with the following code and not getting what I want. With the code below I could only see exit status (0) getting printed in Output_Log.txt:

```
-------SSH Connection opened and command sent to remote server-----
stdout_data = []
stderr_data = []
stdout_data = sys.stdout
stderr_data = sys.stderr
sys.stdout = open('Output_Log.txt','w')
sys.stderr = open('Error_Log.txt','w')

---------Main Code-------------

while True:

 try:
  if session.recv_ready():
    stdout_data.append(session.recv(16384))

  if session.recv_stderr_ready():
    stderr_data.append(session.recv_stderr(16384))

  if session.exit_status_ready():
    break

----------Main code ends-------------------

  except socket.timeout:
    print("SSH channel timeout exceeded.")
    break
  except Exception:
    traceback.print_exc()
    break

 print 'exit status: ', session.recv_exit_status()
 print ''.join(stdout_data)
 print ''.join(stderr_data)
```

Comment: You should have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your python code you should be able to do the following at the end.

```
sys.stdout.write(stdout_data)
sys.stderr.write(stderr_data)
```

Comment: I find your suggestion good, yes, the command will be running on a bash shell but on  a remote server. This python code is running on my computer. So, after the command completes I need to sftp the logs from the server to my computer again. Is that correct ?

Comment: Please see my re-edit, you already have all the code you need to log the responses you have received.

Comment: Tried your suggestion. Getting this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\\folder\transport.py", line 46, in <module>
    sys.stdout.write(stdout_data)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Comment: Got rid of the error by doing :sys.stdout.write(str(stdout_data))
sys.stderr.write(str(stderr_data)) But after re-running the code, I still get all output (error as well as stdout) stuffed into a single file (Output_Log.txt)

Comment: That sounds like your remote process is sending everything on the stdout. You may have to run is manually by ssh'ng into the box and the using my original suggestion of command 1> stdout.log 2>stderr.log to see where the logs are being sent.

Comment: Yes, I agree to that, the box splits the output and errors pretty well to two different logs. But over ssh, when the bytes come to my desktop, it cant split and store them in stdout and stderr. Accepting your first suggestion. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I have no knowledge about sys.stdout or whatever, but have you tried moving some code around? Like write the stuff at the end, or use something like:

```
f = open('Error_Log.txt','w')
f.write(stdout_data)
```

Best guess lol!

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered just using the *logging* module instead?